# Obtaining a list of available functions for a Class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am trying to find a clean, easy way to simply get the list of available functions for a class in Node.js using the command line.

Based on previous web searches I've stumbled upon `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` but it appears that this function is inconsistent, or else I don't understand why it works for some classes but not others.

Let's work through an example and maybe someone can help. Currently, node -v outputs v4.4.5 for this example.

First, suppose I wanted to get a list of the functions for the Math class. From the node console, this works great, I get:

```
[root@localhost /]# node
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)
[ 'E',
  'LN10',
  'LN2',
  'LOG2E',
  'LOG10E',
  'PI',
  'SQRT1_2',
  'SQRT2',
  'random',
  'abs',
  'acos',
  'asin',
  'atan',
  'ceil',
  'exp',
  'floor',
  'log',
  'round',
  'sqrt',
  'atan2',
  'pow',
  'max',
  'min',
  'imul',
  'sign',
  'trunc',
  'tanh',
  'asinh',
  'acosh',
  'atanh',
  'hypot',
  'fround',
  'clz32',
  'cbrt',
  'cos',
  'sin',
  'tan',
  'sinh',
  'cosh',
  'log10',
  'log2',
  'log1p',
  'expm1' ]
>
```

Cool. That works.

Now, since Node.js is more about server side programming, let's see if the same thing works for a common class that is used in nearly every single "hello world" type of example for Node.js: `http.Server`

Let's try the same thing:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(http.Server)
[ 'length', 'name', 'prototype', 'super_' ]
```

Hmmm.... comparing this to the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server), it seems that it's missing basic things like `server.close()`, `server.listen()`. Looking at the docs further, this class is a subclass of `net.Server`, so maybe I have to look at the methods for that class instead. Let's see if that works:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(net.Server)
[ 'length', 'name', 'prototype', 'super_' ]
```

Hmmm... If we compare to the documentation for [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) we're missing basic functions like `server.address()`, `server.getConnections()` and others.

Can anyone help me understand:

(a) Why `getOwnPropertyNames` seems to show all the methods for some classes but not others, and...
(b) Is there another 'official' way to simply list the available functions for an object in Node.js without having to read the API docs to get such a list?

Comment: `getOwnPropertyNames` doesn't climb the prototype tree. Use a `for..in` loop to get all inherited properties.

Comment: OK thanks. Can you give me a quick example that would work on the command line? Would I loop through the `prototype` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) for `getOwnPropertyNames` you will see:

> If you want only the enumerable properties, see Object.keys() or use a for...in loop (although note that this will return enumerable properties not found directly upon that object but **also along the prototype chain** for the object unless the latter is filtered with hasOwnProperty()).

What this is saying is that both `getOwnPropertyNames()` & `Object.keys()` will only return the enumerable properties on the object itself, and won't give you any information about the objects prototype.

So it would seem that there is no built in function to achieve what you want, so you will have to code it yourself. For example:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log('obj.' + prop + ' = ' + obj[prop]);
}
```

*Note: You could make your own utility library, wrapping this idea so that you could include it in any project you want to run it in.*

Comment: Matt - Thanks a lot! This clears up part of my question. I made a small demonstration file that illustrates your loop for `http.Server`

This should allow others to easily try what you suggest:  

     `var http = require('http');
     var serverObj = new http.Server();

     for (var prop in serverObj) {
      //console.log('serverObj.' + prop + ' = ' + serverObj[prop]);
      console.log('serverObj.' + prop);
    } ` 


Your original solution also displays what appears to be the source code for each of the functions. I modified it to just print out the property names.